# Adding Spinner to my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

I have problem with my app. I am beginner. When I added Spinner to my app I can't run it :/. I don't know what can I do that running. I Insert piece app code and report from running.

> 09-19 16:32:09.041    2702-2702/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>      09-19 16:32:09.060    2702-2709/? E/art﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
>      09-19 16:32:09.060    2702-2709/? I/art﹕ Debugger is no longer active
>      09-19 16:32:09.215    2702-2702/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
>      09-19 16:32:09.215    2702-2702/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>          Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 2702
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference
>                   at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
>                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>       09-19 16:33:27.440    2702-2702/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2702 SIG: 9

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    //Spinner
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Spinner
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.maps,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Check line 52... your adapter is null. Check if is calling the data.

Comment: Perhaps also paste in your layout xml file! Looks as if your ID is possibly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
```

And this is my fragment_first

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="First"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_marginLeft="126dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="126dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="177dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And my strings

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>

    <string name="title_section1">1</string>
    <string name="title_section2">2</string>
    <string name="title_section3">3</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string-array name="maps">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>


</resources>
```